# WSDL for WSO2 ESB proxy service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have done a few use cases on WSO2-ESB including protocol mediation with transformation and service-chaining.

In all of them I had to manually write the wsdl for the proxy service. Having experienced other vendor products including Oracle and Tibco where wsdl generation is done by the tool.

**Would it be right to assume in WSO2 ESB one needs to manually write the wsdl file to expose a proxy service on any protocol**, do not see any documents calling that out.
Considering the usage of wsdl in practical use cases.

I have seen posts stating "you can give the WSDL available at your Axis2 service" but most of real time use cases would not be pass through and have custom request and response.

Thanks,
Wajid

Answer (score 1):

I'm also confused with manual wsdl creation. As far as I can see there are gaps in wsdl proxy description. When I do wsdl proxy with WSO2 I have to indicate wsdl to expose 
its either as:

- "none" and I have only mediate function exposed
- "same contract" and this breaks the whole idea of proxy because after that clients read original wsdl and go straight to original server access point.
- or and I have several options to make my own wsdl.

With rich SOAP API (hundreds of methods) none of above work well, considering that manual support of exposed WSDL is rather cumbersome.
I wonder if there is more adequate way for proxying WSDL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java2wsdl generator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/Java2WSDL) tool to achieve the WSDL generation.

Comment: Thanks but this does not help.. Consider I have a WSO2-ESB use case where i do not have any java involved.. like reading a csv file based on request element path and the response element has some subset of the file content being returned. So i would have to manually write a wsdl there to expose this service on http/https.

Answer (score 0):

For the proxies, if you try to restrict access for some operations in your backend service, you can attach customized wsdl to the proxy.
The customization has to be done by yourself and it is simple..
If you want to generate a wsdl fro your service,  jsut deploy the service in wso2as, and check the service dashboard, wsdl option to view the wsdls.